# webpack serve not started

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I can not run webpack serve. My configs:

//webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        open: true,
        compress: true,
        hot: true,
        port: 8080,
        allowedHosts: 'all',
    },
    entry: {
        main: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.js'), // точка входа приложения
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'), // точка выхода приложения, директория
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'webpack Boilerplate',
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/template.html'), // шаблон
            filename: 'index.html', // название выходного файла
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [...],
    }
}
```

// package.json
{
...
"scripts": {
"start": "webpack serve",
"build": "webpack",
"test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1"
},
...
}

Error:

```
skif@PC:~/WebstormProjects/webpack-tutorial$ yarn start
yarn run v1.22.5
$ webpack serve
[webpack-cli] Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'contentBase'. These properties are valid:
   object { allowedHosts?, bonjour?, client?, compress?, devMiddleware?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, http2?, https?, ipc?, liveReload?, magicHtml?, onAfterSetupMiddleware?, onBeforeSetupMiddleware?, onListening?, open?, port?, proxy?, setupExitSignals?, static?, watchFiles?, webSocketServer? }
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
skif@PC:~/WebstormProjects/webpack-tutorial$
```

Any ideas? I don't know what happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove *contentBase* from *devServer* section.
Error is saying that *contentBase* is not among possible options

- allowedHosts
- bonjour
- client
- compress
- devMiddleware
  . . .

Configuration for devServer is here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/

BTW, Webpack4 had *contentBase* option
https://v4.webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devservercontentbase

For the Webpack5 use
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#directory